# srcset in Chrome always showing first image in list

Tags: html, srcset

I'm playing round with srcset for the first time and it seems to be working as expected in all browsers, except Chrome. Chrome will always pick the image which comes first in the srcset list. The code I am using is below.

```
<img 
     srcset="/testPic_1800.jpg 1800w, /testPic_1200.jpg 1200w, /testPic_600.jpg 600w, /testPic_480.jpg 480w"
     sizes="(max-width: 413px) 300px,
            (max-width: 767px) 384px,
            600px"
     src="/testPic_600.jpg" alt="Cars"
     >
```

So in this example, Chrome will always pick the 1800 image, however if I change the order so 480 is first, this will be chosen. Any ideas? Have I got something wrong with my img setup?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Chrome?

Comment: @zcorpan Version 37.0.2062.124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome 37 only supports `x` descriptors, and it thinks all candidates are "1x" so it just picks the first one. Chrome 38 and onward support `w`. You should update your browser. If you want to support old Chromes, use [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill), or just put your `src` candidate also first in `srcset` and have it act as fallback in old Chromes.